# Deploying Rails App to a VPS using Capistrano from Windows to Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

I'm trying to deploy my first rails application to a VPS. So far I have configured it all with ubuntu, postgresql, node, ruby etc and have run the `cap deploy:setup` command without errors. When I try and run `cap deploy:cold`, I get an interesting bundler error which says it can't proceed because of a missing gem, even though it is in the gemfile. I am developing on Windows 7 so can't bundle with unicorn and have put this gem into a group in the gem file:

```
group :production do
    if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /win32/
      gem "pg", :platform => [:mswin, :mingw]
    else
      gem "pg", :platform => :ruby
      gem 'unicorn'
    end
end
```

This is some of the output I get when running `cap deploy:cold`:

```
    ?[2;37mcommand finished in 200ms?[0m
 ** transaction: commit
  * ?[32m2013-02-06 21:11:42 executing `deploy:migrate'?[0m
  * ?[33mexecuting "cd /home/deployer/apps/blog/releases/20130206211131 && bundl
e exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"?[0m
    servers: ["176.58.109.176"]
    [176.58.109.176] executing command
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install
activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfil
e.)
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.
rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in requ
ire'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependen
cy'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <
class:Railtie>'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_ev
al'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hoo
k'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in ru
n_load_hooks'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_ho
oks'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] /home/deployer/apps/blog/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/ge
ms/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:25:in `block (2
 levels) in <top (required)>'
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
 ** [out :: 176.58.109.176] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    ?[2;37mcommand finished in 2926ms?[0m
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/blog/releases/20130206211131 && bundle ex
ec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on 176.58.109.176
```

Any help greatly appreciated, after solid days of trying I'm ready to give up! Many many thanks.

Comment: Assuming that your server is  running Linux (I guess), why don't you change to simply `gem 'pg'` ? You do not need to specify `:platform` and you don't need if .. else ..end .

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I noticed when I looked at the Gemfile.lock that it installed a windows version of pg, so I thought it wouldn't do it any harm putting it in the conditional when it's being deployed on a linux server?

Comment: It seems the conditional is failing in your deploy , according to the log . Keep things simple , when it's possible.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the replies. Changed to `group :production do
 gem "pg", :platform => :ruby
 gem 'unicorn'
end` but still getting the same error. Makes me think maybe it's not deploying as production?

Comment: Also tried `group :production do
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'unicorn'
end` and receiving the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Gemfile`:

```
group :production do 
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'unicorn'
end
```

Remove `:platform => :ruby` .

EDIT : try to specify the environment on the server :

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. I can't have `gem 'unicorn'` as it requires `kgio` which isn't windows compatible and it causes the local bundle to fail.

Comment: I would advice you to switch to VirtualBox with Linux if you don't want to install linux . Win is a constant pain.

Comment: I gave up trying to do rails work on windows about a year ago. It may trick you into thinking that it will be stable, but at any point a new gem install WILL break your windows dev set up. Go right to Ubuntu Virtual Box and save yourself lots of trouble.

Comment: Hey thanks for the revision. Tried that, bundled it, committed it, ran `cap deploy:cold` and got the same error. Makes absolutely no sense!

Comment: Can you post `database.yml`?

Comment: I do have a linux machine too, but as I've never really used it I'm worried about installing java, netbeans, ruby and rails. I guess it would be a good learning experience if it solved this problem... I've been trying to deploy this for 6 days now!

Comment: Believe me , deploying is a simple process and you can do it right now.

Comment: `production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: blog
  password: [removed]`

Comment: Another question: if you try to place `gem 'pg'` outside of `group :production do ... end` , is there a problem ?

Comment: Could it be an issue with the postgresql configuration?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24151/discussion-between-qumara-sixonetour-and-wkdshot)